# Cannot change layers on WPF map?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I am using WPF to display a map, which is created as MPK by ArcMap.

I am trying to change the DBF table and then update the map, but after I remove and then add new layers, the map won't change, the old layer is still there.

What should I do to refresh the map?

I think it may be because it is using cache or something.

Answer (score 1):

Take into account that if you reference the database when you create the MPK, if you change the data in the database it will change. In other hand, if  you choose to attach the database to the MPK, a new version of the database will be created.

An MPK file is a zipped file that contains the mxd file and the geodatabase, if you attached the data. When ArcGIS Runtime display the MPK, it creates a local service that exposes the information within the MXD, to do it, It will uncompress the MPK file to `C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\ArcGISRuntime\Documents\ArcGIS\Packages` (Do you want to change that folder? do it with `ArcGISRuntime.AppDataPath = @"YourPathHere";`)

Go to that location and you will find the geodatabase that ArcGIS Runtime is using.